# Filter items FormArray

Tags: angular, filter

I have a FormArray with this structure:

```
this.salesListArray = this.modeloForm.get('id_listas') as FormArray;

result.forEach(element => {
let formGroup: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    checked: this.fb.control(false),
    id_lista: this.fb.control(element.id_lista[0]),
    nombre: this.fb.control(element.nombre),
    codigoInterno: this.fb.control(element.codigo_interno),
    porcentaje_original: this.fb.control({ value: element.porcentaje_revision, disabled: true }),
    porcentaje: this.fb.control(element.porcentaje_revision, [Validators.min(10), Validators.max(100)]),
    auditoria_original: this.fb.control({ value: element.porcentaje_auditoria, disabled: true }),
    auditoria: this.fb.control(element.porcentaje_auditoria, [Validators.min(10), Validators.max(100)]),
});

this.salesListArray.push(formGroup);
```

And I need to be able to filter through an input by the value of the `nombre`,

Try something like this:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'filter' })
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  public transform(values: any[], filter: string): any[] {
   if (!values || !values.length) return [];
   if (!filter) return values;

   return values.filter(v => v.value.nombre.indexOf(filter) >= 0);
  }
}
```

However, I can not obtain the items, filter them but the values are all empty

Comment: Have you tried with a simple myFormArray.filter ?

Comment: Yes, however when it does not find values I get the error that my FormArray has length 0 @Whisher

Comment: May be I'm wrong but this.salesListArray.push(formGroup); should be inside the forEach loop

Comment: Yes, forget to leave the forEach code, but I found the error, the ngFor must go if or if with an index, that's how it worked.